# get initial value of ngModel in directive

Tags: angularjs

I have a directive that requires `ngModel`. The directive modifies the value stored in `ngModel` (it implements in-place editing of text). Inside my `link` function I need to get the value of `ngModel` before it has been changed.

I tried looking at `ngModel.$viewValue`, and `ngModel.$modelValue`. They both eventually get the model's contents, but in the beginning of the directive's life-cycle they get the raw unprocessed angular expression such as `{{user.name}}`. And I cannot find a way to determine 
when the expression has been processed.

Any ideas?

```
directive('test', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {

        }
    };
})
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `$parse` service:

```
app.directive('test', function($parse) {
  return {
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

      var modelGetter = $parse(attrs.ngModel);
      var initialValue = modelGetter(scope);

    }
  };
});
```

Or:

```
app.directive('test', function($parse) {
  return {
    compile: function compile(tElement, tAttrs) {

      var modelGetter = $parse(tAttrs.ngModel);

      return function postLink(scope, element) {

        var initialValue = modelGetter(scope);

      };
    }
  };
});
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/EfXbjBsbJbxmqrm0gSo0?p=preview